# lo4j2.17.1 wrong timestamp is printed in log files

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

Below is the configuration present in the log4j2config.xml file.

```xml
<!-- Initially for root logger output -->
<RollingFile name="trace" fileName="servers/${sys:weblogic.Name}/trace/default.log" filePattern="servers/${sys:weblogic.Name}/trace/default.log.%i">
  <PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>[%d{MM-dd hh:mm:ss,SSS}:%p %F] %m%n</Pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <Policies>
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
  </Policies>
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
</RollingFile>
```

Log time pattern is picking up as mentioned in this file. But Date and time printed is some wrong date ex: `12-31 07:00:00`. But the actual server time and date is `12-04 00:34`

```
[12-31 07:00:00,000:DEBUG ] Report: NORMAL : 0 : 0 : 0 : 0 : CPU Load:3.22
[12-31 07:00:00,000:DEBUG ] broadcastEvent: Found0 remote receivers
[12-31 07:00:00,000:DEBUG ] broadcastEvent: Forwarded event olpStatReportEvent to local listeners.
```

This issue is happening after upgrading log4j from 1.8.2 to 2.17.1.